# Hibernate hql query exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm getting an error from my @Query, which is the following:

UserRepository.java

```
@Query(value = "select u from User u\n" +
          "  where u.city = :city and u.dentistType = :type\n" +
          "  and (u.firstName like ':name%' or u.lastName like ':name%')")
  List<User> findByCityTypeAndName(@Param("city") String city, @Param("type") DentistType type, @Param("name") String name);
```

From my controller I call the method:

```
List<User> result = userRepository.findByCityTypeAndName(city, DentistType.valueOf(type), name);
```

But when I perform a get request, thus my findByCityTypeAndName method is fired, I get the following error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter with that name [name] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [name] did not exist] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [name] did not exist
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `':name%'` isn't possible. You need to remove the quotes and append the `%` yourself before calling the `findByCityTypeAndName` method.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using concat in your query

```
@Query(value = "select u from User u " +
          "  where u.city = :city and u.dentistType = :type " +
          "  and (u.firstName like CONCAT(:name,'%') or u.lastName like CONCAT(:name,'%')")
  List<User> findByCityTypeAndName(@Param("city") String city, @Param("type") DentistType type, @Param("name") String name);
```

You can also create a method without a query something like this

```
List<User> findByCityAndDentistTypeAndFirstNameStartingWithOrLastNameStartingWith(String city, DentistType type, String firstName, String lastName);
```